# Como corrigir o erro 403 Forbidden?

Tags: http, http-status

Usando o Mozilla quando tento fazer uma busca recebo como resposta "403 Forbidden". O que fazer?

Answer (score 8):

Esse erro sigifica que você tentou acessar alguma coisa para a qual você não pode ter acesso. Um exemplo é tentar acessar uma página que é restrita para administradores do site. Outro exemplo é quando você tenta acessar a listagem de diretórios de um site, e tal acesso foi especificamente proibido para todos.

O Mozilla Firefox não é o culpado por isso. O erro está vindo do site que você está tentando acessar, e não do navegador. Desta forma, para tratar esse erro, o que você tem que fazer depende bastante do site específico que te deu esse erro.

Esse erro é um tanto semelhante ao 404. Quando o servidor de um site emite um erro 404, significa que você tentou acessar uma página que o servidor alega não existir. Já no erro 403, o servidor está alegando que a página pode até existir, mas que você não tem permissão para acessá-la.

Esse erro é diferente do 401, que ocorre quando você não tem acesso devendo fornecer o login e senha primeiramente. No caso do 403, você já forneceu o login e senha e o seu login não tem permissão de acessar a página que você tentou acessar, ou mesmo que você fornecesse algum login e senha, mesmo assim você não teria acesso. Como resultado, o servidor simplesmente se recusa a fornecer o acesso.

Veja [mais sobre os códigos de status HTTP na wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

Em especial sobre o 403, veja [aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403).